# Существование элемента в HTML

Tags: jquery

Не могу поставить условие. Мне нужно определить есть ли в коде HTML элемент с классом ".someclass". Как это сделать?

Что-то вроде такого:

```
if(!$(".someclass"))alert("Is Not DOM element");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if(!$(".someclass").length)alert("Is Not DOM element");
```

обратите внимание:

- [jQuery Tips and Tricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182630/jquery-tips-and-tricks)
- [Закрепляем jQuery — 25 отличных советов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/52201/)
- [5 вещей, которые вы могли не знать о jQuery](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111314/)